# Android Cordova (PhoneGap) + GCM not launching JS function

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I have a simple app that receives push notifications via GCM.

I'm using Cordova + GCM plugin. I have a JAVA portion that shows notification.
JS sends confirmation receipt to server and logs message in SQlite DB.

Once app had been launcher, everything works great.
If I clear memory or reboot the divice, device still receives messages. the Java part shows notifications. However JS function call onMessage does not work (i.e. device does not store message nor sends confirmation receipt).

Here's my log from two scenarios. For some when app is not loaded null is called, instead of GCM_Event...

App loaded, even in background:

```
01-26 16:19:03.958: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10546): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
01-26 16:19:03.958: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10546): GCM IntentService class: com.my.app.GCMIntentService
01-26 16:19:03.958: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10546): Acquiring wakelock
01-26 16:19:04.038: D/GCMIntentService(10546): onMessage - context: android.app.Application@4200bed0
01-26 16:19:04.063: D/GCMIntentService(10546): Dump json: {"message":"","ck":"42","cb":"9999","event":"message"}
01-26 16:19:04.063: V/GCMPlugin:sendJavascript(10546): javascript:GCM_Event({"message":"","ck":"42","cb":"9999","event":"message"})
01-26 16:19:04.068: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10546): Releasing wakelock
```

If app is unloaded, everything is exactly the same, except line before last:

```
01-26 16:19:04.063: V/GCMPlugin:sendJavascript(10546): javascript:null({"message":"","ck":"42","cb":"9999","event":"message"})
01-26 16:19:04.068: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10546): Releasing wakelock
```

Comment: It appears that Cordova WebView is not running at the time of notification. Is there a way to force load the plugin, without launching entire application?

I know people have recommended writing a custom plugin to temporarily store/retrieve messages in Java, but this way I may as well write the entire thing in Java (which I am not well familiar with :( )

Comment: Hi I have exactly the same problem, have you been able to solve it?